# Python tablulate headers and grid lines

Tags: python, pandas, email, sendmail, tabulate

I'm using the following code to print a csv file to the body of an email in html:

```
with open('diff.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
```

But only the first row comes out as a header with bold column headings like the image below:
[image: tablulate-headers]

Is there a way to add grid lines and make each and every section have bold headers, and not just the top row (first line)?

Below is the csv file:

```
DM PROD TORRANCE,DM PROD AUSTIN
dmdirect-api:1.97.3-1d5e546-021822095324,dmdirect-api:1.97.1-031b2fa-021522104034
dsiconfig-init:app1-030222181820,dsiconfig-init:app1-021622212721
dsiconfig-init:fm1-051021191732,dsiconfig-init:fm1-051021200915
dtd-service:2.36.0-a49faef-021622183652,dtd-service:2.35.1-d735bbd-020122161631
fillmagic-service:2.38.3-b876e8c-022422162902,fillmagic-service:2.38.2-9669f38-112221140530
customer-expiration-notification-cli:1.2.2-c80493c-011822135312,
eeligibility-service-cli:master-251852f-042721181924,
providerservices-mysql-cronjob:master-baddfe9-101121133600,
,cascustomer-service:4.8.0-SNAPSHOT-20210623172337-062321102337
,config-init:master-91ea56d-062720021322
,dm-nginx:latest
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
EPS PROD TORRANCE,EPS PROD AUSTIN
customer-expiration-notification-cli:develop-54ec2ab-011822135341,
eeligibility-service-cli:master-251852f-042721181924,
providerservices-mysql-cronjob:master-baddfe9-101121133600,
,config-init:master-91ea56d-062720021322
,dm-nginx:latest
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
UWM PROD TORRANCE,UWM PROD AUSTIN
customer-expiration-notification-cli:1.2.2-c80493c-011822135312,
eeligibility-service-cli:master-251852f-042721181924,
providerservices-mysql-cronjob:master-baddfe9-101121133600,
,config-init:master-91ea56d-062720021322
,dm-nginx:latest
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
BOA PROD TORRANCE,BOA PROD AUSTIN
dsiconfig-init:boa-fm1-011522185758,dsiconfig-init:fm1-051021200915
dsiconfig-init:fm1-051021191732,dsiconfig-init:fm1-072621180451
dsitemplates-init:fm1-051021200319,dsitemplates-init:fm1-051021201016
fillmagic-service:2.37.0-edad1f6-110521145938,fillmagic-service:2.35-5b5f8fe-070821100019
nmlsupdate-cli:1.0-d22848d-100521134007,
sha256:c266c7c161446a8e024e99069ba8d9eb3b01cdf52678b2737955840216e86b18,
,config-init:master-91ea56d-062720021322
,dm-nginx:latest
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
JPMC PROD TORRANCE,JPMC PROD AUSTIN
dsiconfig-init:jpmc-fm1-020822181951,dsiconfig-init:fm1-051021191732
dsitemplates-init:jpmc-fm1-022422155417,dsitemplates-init:jpmc-fm1-020822182115
dsitemplates-init:jpmc-app1-122121173347,dsitemplates-init:jpmc-app1-121621160408
customer-expiration-notification-cli:master-54e1d4b-051121104240,
notarysupplier-service:1.7.4-ba11471-021722111250,
,eeligibility-service-cli:master-251852f-042721181924
,gfs-purge-cronjob:master-712a035-030520220650
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
WF PROD TORRANCE,WF PROD AUSTIN
esignpackage-service:1.7.5-57b7c00-111521160457,esignpackage-service:1.8.1-b6c674d-120121150952
nmlsupdate-cli:1.0-d22848d-100521134007,
```

Thanks in advance.

Hi @Freshpasta, I must be doing something wrong, here is my complete email with your code:

```
import csv, datetime
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

me = 'itops@xxxxxxxx.com'
server = 'smtp-gateway.xxxxxxxx.com:25'
you = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com'

text = """
Team IT Operations


Here is your data:


{table}


Regards,

Team IT Operations"""

html = """
<html><body><p>Team,
<p>Torrance Austin Image Diff Report:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>IT Operations</p>
</body></html>
"""

import pandas

# Read csv file into a dataframe and ignore lines with mutiple commas
# which violate csv format
data = pandas.read_csv("diff.csv", \
                       error_bad_lines=False, \
                       dtype=str, \
                       na_filter=False)

# Detects header rows, change if definition is wrong
def isheader(row):
    for cell in row:
        if not cell.isupper():
            return False
    return True

# Applies styling to header rows
def bolden_uppercase(row):
   if isheader(row):
       # Apply default html th element style
       return ['font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'] * len(row)
   else:
       # Apply no style
       return [''] * len(row)
   
# Style dataframe header rows
style_df = data.style.apply(bolden_uppercase, axis=1)

# Render dataframe as HTML
html_table = style_df.hide_index().render()

# Insert rendered html into string
formatted_html = html.format(table=html_table)

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
message['Subject'] = "Image Diff Report %s" % date
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()

os.remove("diff.csv")
```

Here is my complete email with my old code:

```
import csv, datetime
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

me = 'itops@xxxxxxxx.com'
server = 'smtp-gateway.xxxxxxxx.com:25'
you = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com'

text = """
Team IT Operations


Here is your data:


{table}


Regards,

Team IT Operations"""

html = """
<html><body><p>Team,
<p>Torrance Austin Image Diff Report:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>IT Operations</p>
</body></html>
"""

with open('diff.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
message['Subject'] = "Image Diff Report %s" % date
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()

os.remove("diff.csv")
```

My error is:

```
b'Skipping line 10: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 11: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 12: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 19: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 20: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 21: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 28: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 29: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 30: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 40: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 41: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 42: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 49: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 50: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 51: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 64: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 65: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 66: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 73: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 74: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 75: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 82: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 83: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 84: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 94: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 95: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 96: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 103: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 104: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 105: expected 2 fields, saw 6\n'
```

And then I end up with a table like this:
[image]

Here is the latest screenshot from the pandas formatting code from @freshpasta:
[image: tor-aus-pandas-diff]

Comment: write own code for this. I expect that for all programs this is only one table with one header - and this need to create own code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `b'Skipping line 10: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 11: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 12: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 19: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 20: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 21: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 28: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 29: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 30: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 40: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 41: expected 2 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 42: expected 2 fields, saw `

Comment: @furas, thanks for helping, I had to cut a couple of lines off of the error message as I was over the character limit for stackoverflow. In my original post above, I listed the code I used in my latest attempt, I suspect that my issue is probably due to my own poor use of syntax.

Comment: @puppet_master The mistake is here, ```"alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])``` You should send ```formatted_html``` instead of ```html```. So that line should look like this ```"alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(formatted_html,'html')])```

Comment: The error that's printed is irrelevant, it's just warning you of bad format csv (different number of columns in signaled rows)

Comment: Thank you so much @freshpasta, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hi @freshpasta, the message does send now, and the table does get pasted into the body of the email, however, the capitalized cells don't get formatted bold, and pandas isn't respecting the blank rows to get a little spacing between my diff comparisons. I'll paste a screen shot in the original post.

Comment: Hi @freshpasta, it looks like the for loop is causing groups of records to be repeated in the body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

In csv files there is no concept of sections nor of multiple headers. So python's `tabulate` would offer limited help here.

Since there is no such thing as multiple headers in a csv file, you need to define which rows you consider headers that you need to style. I assume such rows containing only uppercase characters.

Since this question is tagged `pandas` I also assume you can use it for your purpose which I did

```
import pandas

# Read csv file into a dataframe and ignore lines with mutiple commas
# which violate csv format
data = pandas.read_csv("diff.csv", \
                       error_bad_lines=False, \
                       dtype=str, \
                       na_filter=False)

# Detects header rows, change if definition is wrong
def isheader(row):
    for cell in row:
        if not cell.isupper():
            return False
    return True

# Applies styling to header rows
def bolden_uppercase(row):
   if isheader(row):
       # Apply default html th element style
       return ['font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'] * len(row)
   else:
       # Apply no style
       return [''] * len(row)
   
# Style dataframe header rows
style_df = data.style.apply(bolden_uppercase, axis=1)

# Render dataframe as HTML
html_table = style_df.hide_index().render()

# Insert rendered html into string
formatted_html = html.format(table=html_table)
```

Here's the [result](https://rimgo.pussthecat.org/DTIZYdv.png).

Comment: Hi @Freshpasta, my response to your answer is in the original post since I can't make a comment that long. Thank you so much for your help.